# StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries doesn't work as advertised

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

I've come across this several times in the past and have finally decided to find out why.

`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` would suggest that it *removes empty entries*.

So why does this test fail?

```
var tags = "One, Two, , Three,   Foo Bar, , Day    , ";

var tagsSplit = tags.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => s.Trim());

tagsSplit.ShouldEqual(new string[] {
    "One",
    "Two",
    "Three",
    "Foo Bar",
    "Day"
});
```

The result:

```
  Values differ at index [2]
  Expected string length 5 but was 0. Strings differ at index 0.
  Expected: "Three"
  But was:  <string.Empty>
```

So it fails because instead of `"Three"`, we have an empty string – exactly what `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` should prevent.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Most likely because you change the string after the split. You trim the values after splitting them, `RemoveEmptyEntries` doesn't consider the string `" "` empty.

The following would achieve what you want, basically creating your own strip empty elements:

```
var tagsSplit = tags.Split(',').
                  Select(tag => tag.Trim()). 
                  Where( tag => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tag));
```

Comment: As this is the most popular answer and a common need, I went ahead and turned this into a string extension method.  Look for my answer further down the page.

Comment: You can also put the `Where()` before the `Select()` and do the filter first (before the map).

Comment: That would still give empty results when the input string contains something whitespace, e.g. " ". If you use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace instead it would work, and be a performance improvement!

Answer (score 20):

> Adjacent delimiters yield an array element that contains an **empty
>   string ("")**. The values of the StringSplitOptions enumeration specify
>   whether an array element that contains an empty string is included in
>   the returned array.

`"      "` by definition *is not empty* (it is actually *whitespace*), so it is not removed from resulting array.

If you use .net framework 4, you could work around that by using [string.IsNullOrWhitespace method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)

```
var tagsSplit = tags.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                .Select(s => s.Trim());
```

Comment: +1 for showing the usage of how `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` gets rid of the empty entries, but how you still have to then clean up the whitespace.

Answer (score 14):

In .NET 5, they added [`StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=net-8.0#system-stringsplitoptions-trimentries).

Since `StringSplitOptions` has the `[System.Flags]` attribute, it means you can write

```
var tagsSplit = tags.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
```

When both `RemoveEmptyEntries` and `TrimEntries` are specified, it removes both empty values and values which only contain whitespace, whilst trimming all the remaining values.

Comment: I found this much better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

RemoveEmptyEntries do not means space. 
Your input string include many "space". You should notice that "space" is not empty. In computer, space is a special ASCII code. so the code:

```
var tagsSplit = tags.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => s.Trim());
```

means:

1. Split the input by ',' and remove empty entry, not include space. So
   you got an array with some space elements.
2. Then you do trim for each of elements. The space elements become to empty.

That's why you got it.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var tagsSplit = tags.Split(new[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This will spit by comma and space, and eliminate empty strings.

Comment: This will incorrectly treat "Foo Bar" in the OP's input as two separate items.

Answer (score 2):

As this is a very common need, I went ahead and wrapped the most popular answer in a string extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Split_RemoveWhiteTokens(this string s, params char[] separator)
{
    return s.Split(separator).
          Select(tag => tag.Trim()).
          Where(tag => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tag));
}
```

To split on ',' as the other examples, use like this:

```
var result = yourString.Split_RemoveWhiteTokens(',')
```

Note that the return type is IEnumerable, so you can do additional LINQ queries directly on the return result.  Call .ToList() if you want to cast the result to a list.

Answer (score 1):

I've searched also for a clean way to exclude whitespace-entries *during* a Split, but since all options seemed like some kind of workarounds, I've chosen to exclude them when looping over the array.

```
string[] tagsSplit = tags.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string tag in tagsSplit.Where(t => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t))) { }
```

I think this looks cleaner and - as a bonus - `.Split(...).ToArray()` may be ommited.
Of course, it is an option only when you may loop just after split and do not have to store entries for later use.

Answer (score 0):

By `EmptyEntries` it means a case where two delimiters are directly next to each other with nothing in between. Without using this option, it will print a blank line to represent this delimitation. If you use the "RemoveEmptyEntries" option it will not show the delimitation unless there is actually something between the delimiters. A blank space counts as something between the delimiters. If you tried:

```
One, Two,, Three,
```

You should find that `RemoveEmptyEntries` eliminates the delimitation between the two commas and goes straight from Two to Three.

Answer (score -1):

```
var tagsSplit = tags.Split(',')
                    .Where(str => str != String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
                    .Select(s => s.Trim());
```

Comment: The `Where(str => str != String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))` will not compile. `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)` returns a bool and the condition is comparing this to the original `str`.